# I am planning to build a small home sever, What would be best configuration?

Tags: web-server, hardware

My requirement is to build a custom server. On which I will install vmware esxi and then create 2 hardware level virtual machines one Windows server 2008 r2 and one ubuntu server. 
What do you think best configuration would be particular name and model of Processor, RAM and mother board would be appreciated. Price is a constraint. Since I am planning this as a home server. So, for some value for money.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can buy something from eBay rather than building your own server.

Look at this article :

[VMware ESX(i) Home Lab – Why, What and How?](http://www.techhead.co.uk/vmware-esxi-home-lab-why-what-and-how-considerations-when-building-your-own-home-lab)

The HP Proliant ML110 or ML115 should be sufficient and they run quietly. 
Just be careful to buy a CPU that supports Intel VT if you want to run 64 bit VMs.

[HP Proliant ML110 G5 – VT or not VT? That is the question…](http://www.techhead.co.uk/hp-proliant-ml110-g5-vt-or-not-vt-that-is-the-question-when-wanting-to-run-a-hypervisor)

Comment: +1 for mentioning 64 bits of computing. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I know that I'm not meeting your requirements by saying so but if you're only going to run two VMs on this thing, you don't need much of a server. Of course, you don't say what the requirements are for the VMs themselves. If they both require four processors and 32GB of RAM, you'll be building something huge. Given your comments, though, and that you mention you're under price constraints, why not just go with an off the shelf PC for a few hundred  bucks? ESXi will probably work and if not, Hyper-V, VirtualBox, or Xen would work great.